# Agile Development, Maximum Size Project?

Tags: agile

I'm considering running a project using the Agile methodology but the project is roughly 9 months work for 6 developers.  Is this project too big to run under as Agile?

Obviously ignoring the risks associated with running the first Agile project on this size.

Thanks,
Mike

**Edit**

Thanks for all the answers.  I have no experience of Agile neither do I have a Scrum Master or anyone with much xp.  My original thoughts were how to run an agile project as I haven't architected the system yet.  So how do I run a team on a project which doesn't have architecture when the project will last 9-12 months.

Clearly I need to dedicate more time to understanding the principles before I dive in.

Comment: Why would you think the project is "too big" to run as an agile project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not too big at all. However, your question to me seems to imply a kind of casual approach to methodology choice and perhaps an unfamilarity with Agile generally, or you wouldn't ask it - which Agile methodology were you intending to use? Have you experience in that or in other Agile development approaches? How are you proposing to train peoole in what to do?

Comment: +1 Very bold and perfectly valid questions. The Casual Approach has,very wrongly brought Scrum much bad name, instead of the people misusing it. Jeff Sutherland (on googletechtalks) talks about 'shock therapy', used by his very experienced Scrum and Agile Coach, which is a really disciplined version of Scrum and Agile, used at least for the first 3 weeks, to get the concepts of Scrum ingrained and right, for people who take Scrum and Agile casually.

Comment: I think you've nailed it here.  I just don't know enough about it.  I'm going to go off and learn much more about the process before even thinking about implementing it as I would probably crash and burn if I don't do it properly. Thanks.

Comment: The Agile view is that architecture evolves as you go. There is normally a vision of the desired outcome and overall "shape" of the solution, but it's a core principle to leave decisions (like the details of the architecture) to the "last responsible moment" - not at all the same thing as "last possible moment". Ron Jeffries (one of the Agile gurus) points out you will never in future know as little [about your project/software/requirements] as you do now"

Comment: If you organisation will fund it, I would consider using the services of a Agile coach - or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126955/favorite-agile-related-books has some good recommendations. I'd agree with the top voted suggestion. The yahoo! group/email list scrumdevelopment is recommended (but read up a bit first - there's a bit of impatience sometimes with really uninformed/lazy questions)

Answer (score 3):

You have a typical setup here. 6 devs, room for several iterations.

If you had more developers, I would have recommended you to split them into smaller teams.

Project duration is less important since the approach is iterative and let you develop tbe most useful features first.

Answer (score 1):

The project isn't too big to run as an Agile project.

However, you haven't mentioned any other team members.

- Do you have testers and either business users or a BA who can act as a proxy, sat with your developers?
- Do you have stakeholders who are prepared to engage and give you regular feedback?
- Are your infrastructure team ready to provide you with the environments you'll need for more frequent testing, continuous integration, etc?
- Are your architects happy to work in an incremental, evolutionary way?
- Do you have a facilitator or coach who can make a safe environment to run retrospectives in?
- Are the project board prepared to receive different kinds of reports and metrics?
- Are you in a good place to learn and will the people around you make it safe for you to do so?

On an Agile project, the word "team" can be misleading, and the impact of the first Agile project is usually a lot bigger than anyone thinks it will be. Still not too big, though - good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

The [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrum.org/scrumguideenglish/) states:

> The optimal size for a Team is seven people, plus or minus two. When 
>   there are fewer than five Team members, there is less interaction and 
>   as a result less productivity gain. What’s more, the Team may 
>   encounter skill constraints during parts of the Sprint and be unable to 
>   deliver a releasable piece of the product. If there are more than nine 
>   members, there is simply too much coordination required.

Keep in mind "Team" in this context is part of the Scrum Team which also includes the Scrum Master and the Product owner, who are just as key. Do you have a person for each of those roles?

Granted, the Scrum Guide may not be a bible, but it's a good starting reference, especially for someone new to Scrum. But I'd say 6 is a good size for your team.

Are you working with a coach or someone on the Scrum Team who is experienced in Scrum? If not, there's a fair chance that you won't understand a number of key concepts. Said a different way, it's difficult to learn scrum from reading about it and trying it. Often teams that take that approach run into barriers, abandon Scrum, then tell people that "Agile doesn't work" because their project failed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this project too big to run under as Agile?

No. Since you seem to be in the Agile and Estimation and Planning phase it, watch this video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkWglejhJZM

Mike Cohn (author of Agile Estimation and Planning) talks about a 700 people Scrum Project, divided into roughly 100 Teams, which clearly is a several month project.

Now would you think of your project being big? :)

Comment: I think the true leaders can adapt to any methodology. To handle 700 people, you have to use something really good.

Comment: True Leaders would find the courage to use the best possible business processes, engineering practices, and methodologies, and understand that whichever methodology they use, it is the people who use the methodology that succeed or fail, and not the methodology itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would call your project and team as relatively small. Agile methodologies are better for small teams, but the project size doesn't really matter.